# How to write regex for "at least 50 symbols"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need regex for Regular Expression Validator in ASP.NET, that user need to write in message at least 50 symbols(characters). How to do it? I tried

.(dot){50,}  but it doesn't work.

Comment: Isnt there a string length validator?

Comment: I need simple expression for Regular Expression Validator in ASP.NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.{50,}` seems a correct RegExp to me.

However, I think, the regular expression is only checked if the field is not empty, and empty strings are considered valid, so you need to couple this with a `RequiredFieldValidator`.

Comment: I have also RequiredFieldValidator

Comment: then my assumption was incorrect. Could you update your question with the info what exactly goes wrong? How do you check whether the field is valid?

Answer (score 1):

This one should work.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Validator1" runat="server" 
 ControlToValidate="TextBox"
 ErrorMessage="Minimum length is 50"
 ValidationExpression=".{50}.*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{50,}$/
```